# Start an event in WPF

Tags: c#, wpf

I have a textbox which keeps gets data from `INotifyPropertyChanged` MVVM model.

I want to optimize it as such: when I close the window, the data must not be put on to the text box; and when I open the textbox, it should start flowing data again.

This is my viewmodel code:

```
public class serial : NotifyPropertyChanged
{
    private string luminRecevied;

    public string LuminRecevied
    {
        get { return luminRecevied; }
        set 
        {

            if (this.luminRecevied == value)
                return;

            this.luminRecevied = value ;

            this.InvokePropertyChanged("LuminRecevied");

        }
    }
}
```

this is my model code:

```
 //This is where the Outgoing Ports are Tapped and the data is displayed to the serial Monitor.
 var rawPacket = e.Value as RawPacket; // Data recived from the port after tapped 
 StringBuilder sb = new StringBuilder();

 for (int i = 0; i < rawPacket.RawData.Length; i++)
 {
     sb.Append(rawPacket.RawData[i].ToString("X2"));
 }

 this.serialData.LuminRecevied += "RX:"+sb.ToString() + Environment.NewLine;
```

Comment: you have to check the window is open or not. if open then call the **InvokePropertyChange("LuminRecevied")**.

Comment: Your problem is not very clear. You want to display data from a serial-attached device, correct ? Can you write more of your model ? It's lacking some information, like the definition of your event, and how you attach it.

Comment: @jobyjames85 Hi, how do i approach this.

Comment: @cosmo0 hi, yes, i have a window having a textbox. data from serial sort is displaying on it non stop. my doubt is how do i control my data flow.
when i open the window that data must start appending on the text box and when i close the window it must stop fetching data.